# How to send trackback to arXiv papers from a Jekyll blog?

Tags: bash, website, xml, jekyll

Sorry, my question was directed from Academia.SE here by the admins. If there is a better place to ask this question, please let me know as well.

I have recently noticed that arXiv.org website allows trackback links from a blog where an arXiv paper is discussed to be appeared on the paper's abstract page. The [help page](https://arxiv.org/help/trackback#) basically said, to let a trackback link appeared on the arXiv paper abstract page, one only needs to send a special formatted trackback URL to them and some blog websites like WordPress can actually do that automatically.

It looks interesting to have my blog post linked on my arXiv paper page to have people discuss my work on my blog comment section. The problem is I use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) to generate my blog posts and haven’t seen any instructions on how to send the trackback quota to arXiv from a Jekyll generated blog post. Anyone has experience on this?

I can give an example that how I have tried this task. I want to [link my blog post](http://i2000s.github.io/2016/02/17/SQuInT-workshop-2016.html) to the [arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02625), and I can make the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>pingback.ping</methodName>
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>http://i2000s.github.io/2016/02/17/SQuInT-workshop-2016.html</string>
  </value>
 </param>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02625</string>
  </value>
 </param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Then I send this `arxivtrackback150902625.xml` file to arXiv following [these instructions](http://blog.mlindgren.ca/entry/2015/01/17/how-to-manually-send-a-pingback/). However, I got an error on my local computer's bash window:

```
$ curl -X POST -d @arxivtrackback150902625.xml http://arxiv.org/trackback/1509.02625
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<error>1</error>
<message>Bad Permalink URL</message>
</response>
```

Did I miss anything?